# Como pegar o valor de um texto com Cypress?

Tags: cypress

Preciso capturar o texto de um elemento com Cypress. Estou usando:

```js
const test = cy.get('elemento').invoke('text')
cy.log(test)
```

O log mostra: `Object{5}`.

O que tenho que fazer para pegar esse log? Pois gostaria de comparar o valor dessa variável com outro valor mais pra frente.

OBS: Também não consigo fazer a comparação abaixo:

```js
expect(test).to.equal(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar dessa forma:

```js
cy.get('elemento').invoke('text').then(($value) => {
  cy.log($value)
})
```

Caso queira comparar 2 valores:

```js
cy.get('elemento_1').invoke('text').then(($value_1) => {
  cy.get('elemento_2').invoke('text').then(($value_2) => { 
    expect(value_1).to.eq(value_2)
  })
})
```

Qualquer dúvida, segue o link da documentação do Cypress:
[Variáveis ​​e Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Variables)